# MathJax TypeSetting

Tags: mathjax

I'm using MathJax for my personal blog (hosted on Github using Jekyll).

I notice that MathJax equations flicker when I refresh the page, the font was originally relatively small, and it looks thin, and less than half a second later, it would refresh and become much bolder.

I think I like the thin font style and smaller equations (that look much better inline with text) than the bolder version, so I try to configure it but failed. This is the documentation I'm looking at right now: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html#configure-html-css

Here is my set up that's not working:

```js
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        displayMath: [['$$','$$']],
        processEscapes: true,
        skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea"],
        preferredFont: "TeX",
        scale: 90,
        EqnChunkFactor: 1,
        EqnChunk: 1,
        EqnChunkDelay: 10
      }
    });
    </script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf-8"
      src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf-8"
      src="https://vincenttam.github.io/javascripts/MathJaxLocal.js">
    </script>
```

On the side note, I also have this annoying error message `MathJaxLocal.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`.

Would really appreciate if someone answers this question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two fairly different questions but let me wrap them together anyway.

#### flickering

The "flickering" is (probably) the PreviewHTML output )[docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/PreviewHTML.html)). This may be surprising but comes from the fact that the combined configuration file you're loading (`TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML`) MathJax will run the PreviewHTML output first, then the HTML-CSS output (cf. [the combined config docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#the-tex-ams-mml-htmlormml-configuration-file) and the [fastpreview extension docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/extensions/fast-preview.html).

You can use the PreviewHTML output like any other output manually but keep in mind that it is a far less complete (but faster) output processor which does not require webfonts (but uses whatever Times-like fonts the system has).

So following the [configuration docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html), something like

```js
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    messageStyle: "none",
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/PreviewHTML"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
      skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea"]
    }
    TeX: { 
    // whatever is in MathJaxlocal.js
    }
  });
```

#### MathJax not defined

The error is due to the fact that all scripts on the page are loaded asynchronously. Very likely, `MathJaxlocal.js` will load and execute before `MathJax.js` (since it's on the same domain).

You'll need to ensure that the configuration is loaded before MathJax is. Luckily, MathJax can do that for you cf [the docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-a-local-configuration-file-with-a-cdn).

Put your configuration in MathJaxLocal.js and then only load

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=https://vincenttam.github.io/javascripts/MathJaxLocal.js"></script>
```

See the link on how to add other configuration files, including combined ones from the CDN - which would make sense if you want to go back to a full output processor as the combined configurations are packaged more efficiently.

Comment: Ah! Yes, thank you!! By switching to just PreviewHTML, it worked! However, some equations become unreadable due to the incompleteness. Then may I ask if there's a way to just reduce the font-size or font-weight of the MML output? The current equation font looks too big and heavy...

Comment: You cannot change reduce the weight below its minimum. You can change the font size (e.g. using CSS) but then the x-height will no longer match the surrounding font (that's a feature of MathJax). In my experience, you probably want to test if another font supported by MathJax works better with your surrounding font. check the documentation for how to switch fonts.

Comment: That was very insightful and educational! Thank you :)

Comment: Peter has given you the correct solution, but one thing he said is not quite right.  He says all the scripts on the page are loaded asynchronously, but that is not true.  The scripts *are* loaded synchronously in your case, but because you are using the old CDN, the `MathJax.js` file on that server is loaded synchronously, but it redirects you to the new CDN by inserting a new script to load from there (and that script *is* asynchronous).  If you had changed to the cdnjs.cloudflare.com address, then your page would have worked as it has in the past.  A small nit-pick.

Comment: @davide yeah I thought that too at first. But the source doesn't match the html on the page where the source is processed into an async call by Octopress. I should've said that clearly though.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, OK, thanks for clarifying.  I was going by the code given, and didn't realize that it would be modified by the content management system.  I didn't see a link to the actual page, so couldn't check there.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I got carried away so much. The local config file in the OP points to a github.io page.